# Smalldatetime ToString in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, tostring

I have a smalldatetime field that I am trying to convert to a string in LINQ.
This is my current code:

```
var entities = from a in dbcontext.Article
where a.PubDateTime.ToString("ddMMyyyy") == pubDate
select a;
```

However I get the following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated
>   into a store expression.

I have read a few posts however I can't seem to get it to work.
Any pointers would be great.

Comment: can you convert `pubDate` to a DateTime first?

Comment: Why not use `DateTime.Compare` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error speaks for itself, you can't use a User defined method that can't be translated to SQL through Linq to Entities. You can see a full article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb738550%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Assuming that your `pubDate`is a string, please try that following code

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(pubDate); // You may have to specify your own format
DateTime date2 = DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate,"ddMMyyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.Invarian‌​tCulture); // Like suggested by XenoPuTtSs

// choose date or date2, according to your needs

var entities = from a in dbcontext.Article
    where a.PubDateTime == date
    select a;
```

You may also have trouble with time when comparing dates like that, so you could check [DbFunctions.TruncateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220142%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Comment: you can use this to parse the date.  DateTime.ParseExact(pubDate,"ddMMyyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);